# Formulating research question

Tags: phd, graduate-school, advisor

I am international student and have a problem with formulating a research question. I know the gap, but I could not make it clear. + my supervisor is not convinced of what I am doing and believes that there is no problem really(the research gap). 
Any advice.!
Thanks,

Comment: What is your question? Did you intend to write something after "thanks"? Welcome to the site!

Comment: If you can't make it clear to your supervisor then you have nothing to work with. That is pretty much a minimum requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The question is very general so the answer is going to be as well.

A research question is a plan for working on some specific piece of research. Making the plan clear is an essential step. You should be able to give a specific answer to the three standard questions:

- **What is it?** What is the object of the work and what is the context? Are there any similar questions already solved or studied in the literature?  How does your goal/question differ from existing works?
- **Why does it matter?** What are the motivations for doing this work? What problem does it solve (or contribute to solve)? what use cases does it apply to?
- **How?** Which method can be used? Why this method in particular? What are the potential limitations of this approach?

Having a clear answer to all these questions will allow you to have a discussion about the details with your supervisor: either they are convinced by your plan, or they can tell you exactly where is the problem in your plan.

Comment: @Mary Paraphrasing a professor at UPitt in the U.S., you need to first convince yourself before you can convince the world. Ensuring that you deeply understand your question will help you convince other people.